# Linux how to set and get current dhclient ID

Tags: linux, dhcp

I've been having problems with the dhclient ID that my Linux box (yocto) sent out. I will like to know how do I check and set the dhclient ID on linux?

Comment: On what version of which Linux OS? What exactly is the problem? Please update your question, don't answer in comments.

Comment: Do you mean dhclient specifically, or do you mean "DHCP client" in general? There are many choices for a DHCP client on Linux, and only one of them is actually called 'dhclient'. (More commonly, it's the systemd DHCP client that sends unusual client IDs.)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310)? Please [edit] and state the actual problem(s) instead of asking about what you think a solution may be.